# Pass values from parent directive to child directive after $http has returned

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My parent module has a parent controller and a parent directive. There are a few child directives within the parent directive which shares parent's model. The model is modified in the parent's controller by a $http service call. The child directive gets some data via attributes which is essentially a $scope member of the parent. Now I want the children directives to be compiled after the $http call has gotten the response data. I am trying to avoid $parent as the child directives are re-usuable. Is there a way I can do this?

I am working on an example jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ng-if="!!dataChildNeedFromParent"` on the children - this means that only when data available on the parent, the condition in ngIf would be true, and only then the children will compile and render.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use require in the child directive. That will require the parent controller so you need a controller there with the functionality you want the children directives to use.